# postgresql insert values from a select query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert values from a select query using this:

```
INSERT INTO cb (vol_sec)
SELECT sum(vol)
FROM cb
GROUP BY cusec;
```

but the error message is ERROR:  the value null for column «id» restriction violates not null. I have tried to change NOT NULL to NULL but i have another message 'The column <> is in the primary key.
Is there any way to avoid this errors?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the schema of the table?

Comment: Your target table as an `id` column which is a primary key (hence `NOT NULL`), but doesn't have a default value. You probably need to add a sequence (or use an existing one if appropriate) and set the `DEFAULT` for `id` to grab the next value of that sequence. But of course, the exact details of your database schema and/or the way you use that table may have an influence on what exactly you should be doing.

Comment: Due to the large number of fields I could share the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be follow the step :

1. drop the constraint PRIMARY KEY

   ALTER TABLE schema.cb  DROP CONSTRAINT name_of_constraint;
2. update the constrait not nul .

   ALTER TABLE schema.cb ALTER COLUMN id DROP NOT NULL;
3. execute your insert.

Answer (score 2):

As `id` column in target table `cb` is primary key and it seems you does not define any default value for `id` column.

when value is inserted in `cb` table there is no value for primary column `id`. so you are getting this issue.

> ERROR: the value null for column «id» restriction violates not null.

try for assign value to primary key column `id`. you can do it by changing column data type to `serial` it will auto increment.
drop the table `cb` and create with updated data type for `id`

```
--drop TABLE cb;
    CREATE TABLE cb
    (
      id integer serial,
       vol_sec integer,
      --other columns,
      CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

First i apologize for the delay. All your comments helped me to solve the problem. Following the steps proposed i finally got to insert the column (id) as serial type and executing the query the data were inserted successfully. Thanks.

Comment: You should accept the answer the solved your problem.